# Change mosh kill command shortcut

Tags: ssh, mosh

Is there any way to change [mosh](https://mosh.org/) kill/suspend mapping <kbd>ctrl+^</kbd> to something else?

The reason it's the same key with `vim` quick buffer switch, it's annoying when you're trying to switch buffer but mosh ask whether to suspend, kill or repeat the key to send literal <kbd>ctrl+^</kbd>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the man page, you can select the escape character by setting an environment variable to it before running mosh, eg

```
MOSH_ESCAPE_KEY=$'\x11' mosh ...
```

where `$''` is shell syntax to allow you to enter a character by its octal or hex code (x11 is control-Q). Make sure your shell understands that syntax. Note, you cannot use a symbolic representation such as `C-Q` or `^Q`.

Comment: You are right. Thank you!

Comment: for a complete list of all control key combinations: http://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/scen103/ascii.html